# Resolving a object list before route load in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Good day
i'm trying to resolve a property in an angular js project. below is what i've done so far,

```
    .when('/wizard',{
    controller:'WizardController',
    templateUrl: 'partials/wizard.html',
    access: access.user,
    resolve: {
        categories: function ($http) {
                var cats=  ;
                var promise = $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: '/categories',
                });
                promise.success(function(data){

                    console.log('Data successfully retrieved');

                    cats = data;
                });

                promise.error(function(){
                    console.log('Couldn\'t fetch categories' )
                });

                //categories =  
                //      [{"id":"1","category_name":"Testing"},
                //      {"id":"2","category_name":"Testing 2"},
                //      {"id":"3","category_name":"Testing 3"},
                //      {"id":"4","category_name":"Testing 4"}];
                return cats;



            }
        }

    })
```

I'm trying to access the categories in my view
i've already set the $scope.categories to be equal to a injected categories that was resolved

```
    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
                <label for="category">Project Category</label>
                  <select ng-model="project.category" ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in categories">
                  <option value="">-- Choose Category --</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

I can't seem to figure what i'm doing wrong!

Comment: `cates = data;` not sure that will fix it, but it is a type -o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The categories property of resolve object should return a promise where as you are returns a array, that gets reassigned in the future.

The categories method should be written like

```
resolve {
   categories:function($http) {
     return $http({method: 'GET',url: '/categories'});
   }
}
```

Then you would get the categories dependency in your controller.

If you look at your logic, it is reassinging the reference to `cats` after the http callback is complete, whereas the reference returned is to another object.

In any case better to return promise

Comment: Thanks, i have abstracted it into a service and i return promises from the service.